Type narrowing for two variables
interface A {
   type: "A";
   propsOfA: string;
}

interface B {
   type: "B";
   propsOfB: number;
}

interface C {
   type: "C";
   propsOfC: boolean;
}

function isEqual(a: A | B | C, b: A | B | C) {
  if (a.type !== b.type) {
    return false;
  }

  switch (a.type) {
    case "A": {
      return a.propsOfA === b.propsOfA;
    }
    case "B": {
      return a.propsOfB === b.propsOfB;
    }
    case "C": {
      return a.propsOfC === b.propsOfC;
    }
  }
}

Error on all return statements in the switch case, because type b is not narrowed along with a (here shown for the first case):
Property 'propsOfA' does not exist on type 'A | B | C'.   
  Property 'propsOfA' does not exist on type 'B'. [2339]

Is there a clean way to do this? The only solution I see is to have 9 type checks aka. a switch/if for b in each case of a.

It works if you put the type comparison inside each switch case, i.e. case "A": return b.type == a.type && a.propsOfA === b.propsOfA;. Not posting this as an answer because it doesn't qualify as a clean way, but at least it's cleaner than your proposed solution.

You can use assertion function to assert that a.type === b.type (Playground), in this case assertion is a logical choice because b.type is certainly equal to a.type, and will not cause a runtime error, unfortunately typescript can't narrow two variables based on one of them.

Slightly cleaner than Thomas's suggestion is return b.type === 'A' && ....

This is mostly beyond TS's pay grade. Even if the argument list were known to be of type [x: A, y: A] | [x: B, y: B] | [x: C, y: C] you couldn't check args[0].type to narrow it, because that would be a nested discriminated union and TS doesn't support those.

The Typescript compiler does not track dependencies between different variables in this way, so it doesn't "remember" that a.type and b.type are equal, for instance. This has been variously requested as a feature, but e.g. this issue shows the Typescript team don't currently consider it worth implementing.

If it was my code, I would probably write it this way:
  switch (a.type) {
    case "A": {
      return b.type === "A" && a.propsOfA === b.propsOfA;
    }
    case "B": {
      return b.type === "B" && a.propsOfB === b.propsOfB;
    }
    case "C": {
      return b.type === "C" && a.propsOfC === b.propsOfC;
    }
  }

That's three checks instead of nine. However, this might look inelegant since a.type === b.type is one check rather than three. An alternative approach is to construct a version of the union type where it's OK to write b.propsOfA without narrowing on b.type === "A":
interface A {
    type: "A";
    propsOfA: string;
    propsOfB?: never;
    propsOfC?: never;
}

interface B {
    type: "B";
    propsOfA?: never;
    propsOfB: number;
    propsOfC?: never;
}

interface C {
    type: "C";
    propsOfA?: never;
    propsOfB?: never;
    propsOfC: boolean;
}

With the types declared this way, your original code compiles with no errors. This is also actually a little safer than the original version, since it forbids objects like {type: "A", propsOfA: "foo", propsOfC: true} which are assignable to the original type A.
If the above is too much to write out manually, you can also construct these types programmatically:
/**
 * Makes a discriminated union type "safe" by requiring properties specific
 * to some branches to be absent in other branches.
 */
type SafeUnion<T> = Simplify<T> extends infer _T ? _T extends unknown ? Replace<{[K in AnyKeyOf<T>]?: never}, _T> : never : never

/**
 * Simplifies a type to make it more readable.
 */
type Simplify<T> = T extends unknown ? {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} : never

/**
 * Similar to an intersection `S & T`, except shared properties take their
 * types only from `T`.
 */
type Replace<S, T> = Simplify<T & Omit<S, keyof T>>

/**
 * The keys of any member of a union type.
 */
type AnyKeyOf<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never

Then your code can be written like:
type ABC = SafeUnion<A | B | C>

function isEqual(a: ABC, b: ABC) {
    // ...
}

Playground Link

@jcalz Thank you, I went looking for an existing issue but didn't find one in a few minutes of search.

This works, is explicit and clear, and is only slightly repetitive:
function isEqual(a: A | B | C, b: A | B | C) {
  if (a.type == "A" && b.type == "A") {
    return a.propsOfA === b.propsOfA;
  }
  if (a.type == "B" && b.type == "B") {
    return a.propsOfB === b.propsOfB;
  }
  if (a.type == "C" && b.type == "C") {
    return a.propsOfC === b.propsOfC;
  }
  return false;
}

